# Spawn Bash Shell in Go

Tags: go

I'm writing a bot to play music in Go, and I'm having some trouble getting this bash shell to work

```
proc := exec.Command("/bin/bash")
stdin, errIn := proc.StdinPipe()
stdout, errOut := proc.StdoutPipe()
WriteAndWait(stdin, stdout, "cd /home/user/bot1337/")
WriteAndWait(stdin, stdout, "rm song.mp3")
WriteAndWait(stdin, stdout, "youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 " + Sanitize(command[1]))
WriteAndWait(stdin, stdout, "mv *.mp3 song.mp3")
WriteAndWait(stdin, stdout, "xmms2 play song.mp3")
WriteAndWait(stdin, stdout, "quit")
```

The WriteAndWait function

```
func WriteAndWait(stdout io.Writer, stdin io.Reader, command string) {
    stdout.Write([]byte(command + "; echo -e '\\x63\\x68\\x65\\x63\\x6b'\r\n"))
    buf := make([]byte, 256)
    for {
        fmt.Println("Reading...")
        rlen, _ := stdin.Read(buf)
        strin := string(buf[:rlen])
        fmt.Println(strin)
        if strings.Contains(strin, "check") {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The process gets created, but it the program hangs on Read() - it can never read anything from stdin

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why are you using `\r\n`, that's windows line ending, not Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to start your process. `exec.Command` creates the process object, but does not start it.

Just put `proc.Start()` after your pipe init and it should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I thought that exec.Command already started the process, and that .Run() would force it to block until the program finished. I had no idea you were supposed to start it with .Start(). Thanks!